# Is there a method to determine if a file path is nested within a directory path in .Net

Tags: .net, path, filesystems

I want to determine if a folder contains a file, when both are specified by a path.

At first glance this seems simple. Just check if the file path starts with the directory path. However, this naive check ignores several issues:

- Paths may be relative or absolute
- Paths may use the alternate directory separator
- Paths may use inconsistent casing, which matters depending on the OS
- Different paths may refer to the same location
- Probably some more that I don't know about

Is there an existing method in the framework, or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in .NET method to do this, but the following function should accomplish this using the FileInfo and DirectoryInfo classes:

```
public static bool FolderContainsFile(String folder, String file)
{
    //Create FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);

    DirectoryInfo currentDirectory = fileInfo.Directory;
    if (dirInfo.Equals(currentDirectory))
        return true;

    while (currentDirectory.Parent != null)
    {
        currentDirectory = currentDirectory.Parent;

        if(currentDirectory.Equals(dirInfo)
            return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Yes, that will work quite nicely (assuming there is not a framework method). Edit the answer to state whether or not a framework method exists and I'll accept it.

Comment: DirectoryInfo instances are not necessarily equal even if two paths resolve to the same actual directory.  This is try for casing and other formatting differences, like trailing slash, etc.  In other words, `dirInfo.Equals` is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it'll work in all cases, but I'd suggest looking at [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx).

Quote: *Returns the absolute path for the specified path string.*

Comment: GetFullPath doesn't normalize casing.