# What is the most efficient/elegant way to filter a path list by a base path?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, path, filtering

What is the most efficient/elegant way to filter all paths by a base path?

I have a path list and a base path, and I want a to get a list of paths that are children of the base path:

```
public IList<string> FilterPathList(IList<string> paths, string basePath)
{
  // return a list of paths that are children of the base path
}
```

Sample input:

```
c:\foo\bar\file1
c:\foo\bar\file2
c:\foo\bar\dir1\file11
c:\foo\bar\dir2\file
c:\foo\other\file1

Base path -> c:\foo\bar
```

Expected output:

```
c:\foo\bar\file1
c:\foo\bar\file2
c:\foo\bar\dir1\file11
c:\foo\bar\dir2\file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

`paths.Where(p => p.StartsWith(basePath)).ToList();`

You may want to flesh out the Where to make the comparison case-insensitive, unless of course, you normalise the case.

This will also return the base path if it's in the list.

Comment: This won't take casing or \ vs / into account! Consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660205/is-there-a-method-to-determine-if-a-file-path-is-nested-within-a-directory-path-i

Comment: @Strilanc I said it wouldn't take casing into account, but the question is about an elegant way to traverse the list, the content of the where can be expanded.  Also, the question clearly states the type of input it is scanning, doesn't use forward slashes.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed the answer too fast to see the casing note. However, the question does not state that the paths are guaranteed to use a particular separator (the examples just happen to use only one). Even if that was stated, it's a dangerous assumption to make.

Comment: @Strilanc I can only work on what's given.  I don't disagree it's a dangerous assumption, but technically I'm not making any assumptions - the OP is.

Answer (score 3):

Using (Parallel)-LINQ:

```
public IList<string> FilterPathList(IList<string> paths, string basePath)
{
    var result = from s in paths.AsParallel()
                 where s.StartsWith(basePath)
                 select s;
    return result.ToList();
}
```

The `AsParallel()` does the work in multiple threads (if big enough and >1 CPU) so it should be faster, but be aware that it could/will change the order of the list.

Comment: Unless you use [AsOrdered()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered.aspx).